# How to search text using php if ($text like %admin%)

Tags: php, sql-like

How to search text using php?

Something like:

```
$form = $_GET['form'];

if($form like %admin%){
  $form = 1;
}

if($form like %user%){
  $form = 2;
}
```

and then I can use this query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE type = $form ;
```

Comment: use `stristr();` Reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php

Comment: `stristr()` and `strstr()` are less efficient than `stripos()` and `strpos()`  Read the manual link provided.  When you are just checking for the existence of a substring, use strpos/stripos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with user input, you can't be lazy with validation.

Sahil's answer will set `$from` to `2` if `$_GET['form']=='adminuser'`.
It also uses `stristr()` which is not recommended (even by the php manual) for this case for performance reasons.

Unless you have a valid reason for checking for a substring, you should be checking the entire string.  Also, you should use just one condition block rather than two separate if blocks -- this will avoid overwriting `$form` and doing extra unnecessary function calls.

```
if(isset($_GET['form']) && $_GET['form']=='admin'){
    $form=1;
}else{
    $form=2;  // assuming this should be the default form value
}
```

...or `$form=isset($_GET['form']) && $_GET['form']=='admin'?1:2;`

---

If you are going to continue checking for substrings:

```
if(isset($_GET['form']) && strpos($_GET['form'],'admin')!==false){
    $form=1;
}else{
    $form=2;  // assuming this should be the default form value
}
```

...or `$form=isset($_GET['form']) && strpos($_GET['form'],'admin')!==false?1:2;`

Depending on your possible values for `$_GET['form']` your validation will be improved if you check for the location of `admin` -- does the string start with `admin` or end with it or neither?

Comment: Good critical answer. But I have finished the project.

My expectation is to make a search filter with php, and use $form value for other purposes. My code is work, but there is something weird when I enter the letters that used to both words.

For error example if I change "admin" and "user" into "male" and "female".
If I type "male", both %male% and %female% is TRUE.

Comment: @D.AjiPratama   Yes, true, you should use: `strpos($_GET['sex'],'male')===0` or `!==0` to check the offset (ensure it is the start of the string).

Comment: ...but really, you should be checking whole strings, not chopping substrings from them.  This seems like an indication that your form fields are not suitably structured.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strpos`

```
 if (strpos($form,'admin')!== false) {
 $form = 1;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$form = $_GET['form'];

if(stristr($form,"admin")){
  $form = 1;
}

if(stristr($form,"user")){
  $form = 2;
}
```